# Local Security Policy applied through Group Policy does it append or replace?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows

Do Local Security Policy settings, specifically those under User Rights Assignment, replace or append the existing settings when applied through a Group Policy Object?  What about the settings applied through other GPO's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings that are defined in domain GPOs override settings on the local machine.  Settings that are undefined in the domain GPO will remain with the settings in the local policy.

A great way to test is to use Resultant Set of Policy.  It will tell you where and through what means settings are applied.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something to thnk about if using Vista SP1 or above

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772175.aspx